# How to get a side of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to get the side $(a)$ of a triangle knowing the angle $(B)$ adjacent to that side $(a)$, the other adjacent side $(c)$ to that angle $(B)$ and the opposite side $(b)$ to the angle $(B)$.

[image: example]

Example values:

- B) $25$ degrees
- c) $3$ units
- b) $2$ units

Its possible to get $a$ with this values?

I have tried to use online trigonometry calculators but I cant figure out the right formula, if even possible, since the calculators don't appear to have one readily available even in two steps.

Comment: [Solution of triangles from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles#Two_sides_and_non-included_angle_given_(SSA))

Comment: thanks, I don't understand on that solution in Wikipedia is why they are solving `y` first but then once solved use `a`. I'm I missing something? or is a typo?

Comment: Well, the goal of that page is to solve all the unknowns ($\gamma,\alpha, a$). At last that page also gives a direct formula for the unknown side $a$ based on the given values.

Comment: I am sorry I amiss the part they solve for `α`, so in that case i need to solve first `γ` then `α` and finally `a`

Comment: @peterwhy this solution from wikipedia suits me best, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another alternative by law of sine we can find the angle $C$ that is

$$\sin C= \frac c b \sin B$$ and then, since $\cos C=\pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2 C}$, we have

$$a=c\cos B + b\cos C=c\cos B \pm b\sqrt{1-\sin^2 C}$$

[image]
with plus sign forthe solution with  $C$ acute and minus sign for the solution with $C$ obtuse .

Comment: It seems like only the second equality relied on $C$ being acute, right?

Comment: @Ian Yes, indeed. From the given data it seems we are in a case with $C$ acute, otherwise we should take $- \sqrt{1-\sin^2 C}$, as you noticed with your solution.

Comment: @Ian I've modified a littel bit to make more clear that point. Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I understood right, the equations are the same as follows right?
$$c * \cos(B) + b * \cos(C) = c * \cos(B) + b * \sqrt{1-\sin(C)^2}$$
my question comes since I plugged all equations provided in all answers to benchmark and yours were quite faster but returned consistently a different results (~.5 to 1 higher) than the others. ( I added only + since that's what I am looking after )

Comment: @Barreto For $C$ acute it should work fine, if you give me the data you are using, I can check for the result.

Comment: [here is the program](https://sharplab.io/#gist:fdfde20178d429dd2759d749c4211bed)
online the benchmark doesn't correspond to my machine results, but the math is still the same, and the Values I run in this program were `B` - 16 and 19 `c` 3, 4 and 5 with b as 2 constantly. some value combinations would return NaN so that's why I opted by this values (yours are LawOfSines 2 and 3)

Comment: I am sorry I had a bug on that two formulas, it was due to autocompletion I just noticed now. its perfect now and still runs faster than all the others previously added.
for good measure [here is the updated program](https://sharplab.io/#gist:869fb361c3bd5c42fb911c3c3fc1b332) and I added one more formula that actually beats all the answers (came from the comment pointing at wikipedia where I get all the angles first)

Comment: @Barreto Well done! Indeed looks an effective approach also to me. You are welcome, Bye.

Answer (score 5):

You can find $a$ using *Law of cosines*:
$$b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos(B)$$
$$a^2 - 2ac\cos(B) + (c^2 - b^2) = 0$$
$$a = c\cos(B) \pm \sqrt{c^2\cos^2(B) - (c^2-b^2)} = c\cos(B) \pm \sqrt{b^2-c^2\sin^2(B)}$$

Comment: thanks for the formula, I am not very experienced but I am assuming that solving either of the formulas in the last line will give me the same result? 
Note that I changed the naming on my question to follow "usual notation" referred in other answer

Comment: @Barreto You mean the two sides of the second equals sign? Yes, those give the same result. The $+$ and $-$ in the $\pm$ do not give the same result.

Answer (score 4):

This is the "SSA" case, where you usually have either 0 or 2 such triangles up to congruence. That might explain why canned trig solvers choke on it, though really this is a familiar case that should be coded in.

Switching to the usual notation (where vertices are capital letters and side lengths are the length of the opposite side), you have $\sin(C)=c \sin(B)/b$ from the law of sines. Of course you must have $C<180^\circ-B$ as well.

Given $c,B$ and $b$, there are either 0, 1, or 2 values of $C$ between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ-B$ satisfying these requirements, depending on whether $B$ is acute and on how $c \sin(B)/b$ compares to $1$.

Having picked one, you have $a=b \sin(180^\circ-B-C)/\sin(B)$ from the law of sines again.

In your example you get either $C \approx 39^\circ$ or $C \approx 141^\circ$, and the value of $a$ you get is different in these two cases.

As in the other answer, you can also use the law of cosines; going that way, solving the resulting quadratic equation yields the same 0/1/2 solution structure as this method.

Comment: I edited the question to accommodate that notation, thanks for the explanation, I will try this "two step" formula,  [I thought I was close here but I couldn't figure out the two steps](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/triangle-law-of-sines.php) tried to get `c` in this case but to get `C` would need `c` and vice versa

Comment: @Barreto You said you had $c$ and what I called $b$ (what you called $d$), and were trying to find $a$.

Comment: I meant on the link, as an example, they don't have `d` on there

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer that mentions that there are two solutions (or zero).